# Read IntegerType from NSInputStream

Tags: swift, generics

I am trying to write a generic function that will read an int-typed value from `NSInputStream`:

```
func read<T : IntegerType>() -> T? {
    var buffer : T = 0

    let n = withUnsafePointer(&buffer) { (p) in
        self.read(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(p), maxLength: sizeof(T))
    }

    if n > 0 {
        assert(n == sizeof(T), "read length must be sizeof(T)")
        return buffer
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

I am basing this on my previous Google searcg:
    https://gist.github.com/ishikawa/c3917ea4daa107f1ce68

Everything seems just fine, except for one thing:

`withUnsafePointer(&buffer)` shows an error:

`Cannot convert value of type 'inout T' to expected argument type 'inout _'`

I am unsure, how to fix this - or if this approach is completely wrong and won't work...

Anyone any ideas?

EDIT:

The desired functionality:

```
let i: Int8 = stream.read()
let o: UInt32 = stream.read()
// etc.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `read()` method requires a *mutable* buffer pointer:

```
let n = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&buffer) { (p) in
    self.read(UnsafeMutablePointer(p), maxLength: sizeof(T))
}
```

The placeholder type `<UInt8>` in `UnsafeMutablePointer(p)` can be inferred automatically from the context.

Note that there is a general problem with your approach: If the input
stream is not connected to a real file but to some communication channel
(e.g. a TCP socket, pipe, ...) then the only guarantee is that `read()`
waits until *at least one byte* is read and the assertion `n == sizeof(T)`
can fail. You have to read again in a loop until the required amount
is read.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Not sure how I could have missed this minor issue - Xcode's error message doesn't make it any easier either... Anyhow, I mainly use this on `NSData` that is already in memory, so this is not an issue. I previously had this approach in ObjC, but since I never used it (since I'm working with streams from in-memory data) I decided not to implement it ATM, since dealing with integer types in Swift is hell. (I'd need to be able to shift the result `<< 8`, but `IntegerType` doesn't declare the `<<` operator, etc, etc.)