# How do I read data into a data structure from a function that accepts an UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>?

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

I'm reading data from a socket with an `NSInputStream`. This works great when the data is read into an array of UInt8s with the following:

```
var buffer = [UInt8](count: 1024, repeatedValue: 0)
let len = inputStream.read(&buffer, maxLength: buffer.count)
```

where `inputStream` is an `NSInputStream` and the `read` method's first parameter is an `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>`.

My question is how do I read the input data into a data structure other than a UInt8 array, such as the `message` object below:

```
struct Message {
    var id:Int
    var data:Float
    init() {
        id = 1
        data = 1.0
    }   
}

var message = Message()
```

I've tried everything I could think of and searched SO with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The same approach as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356178/read-integertype-from-nsinputstream should work here. But note that – as far as I know – Swift makes no statements about the *layout* of a struct (padding, alignment), so it might be better to define a C struct and import that.

Comment: @MartinR The answer in the link was exactly what I needed. Thanks for your help.