# What's the best way to consume the bytes of NSData?

Tags: swift, parsing, nsdata, binary-data, nsinputstream

I'd like to parse some binary data. In Java I would use [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class, which has really nifty methods like `getInt()`, `getChar()`, etc. which will return you the correct length of data, and advance the (internal) "read head".

The closest I could find in Swift is `NSInputStream`, which requires you manually manage a buffer, set the number of bytes to read, ensure the correct amount was read, etc. It's quite clunky. Are there any better APIs I'm overlooking?

Comment: What are you using this for? Would NSCoding suit your needs?

Comment: @jtbandes I'm trying to parse `.ani` files. As far as I know, `NSCoder` only deals with decoding data encoded with `NSCoder`

Comment: So are you using NSData at all, or NSFileHandle? It would be pretty simple to make a couple extensions on NSFileHandle to do what you want.

Comment: @jtbandes Currently, `NSData`, but it's flexible. `NSFileHandle` looks promising

Comment: For testability you could abstract over them with a protocol e.g. `ContiguouslyReadable`. Then you could make a simple struct which wraps an NSData along with a "read head", so you don't have to actually use a file handle if you don't want to open a file.

Comment: @jtbandes How would you read from the `NSData`? `func getBytes(UnsafeMutableRawPointer, range: NSRange)`?

Comment: @MartinR As I mention in my question, I'm aware of `(NS)InputStream`. But  manually reading into a buffer, managing the size of the buffer, and the amount actually read, etc. is quite annoying. Ideally, having something with simple functions like `getInt`, `getBool`, etc. would be really convenient.

Comment: Yes I realized that and deleted my previous comment. I am not aware of existing methods like that. If you want to add them as extensions, a generic approach as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356178/read-integertype-from-nsinputstream might help.

Comment: @MartinR Oh that's pretty nice, I'll check it out!

Comment: @MartinR Am I missing something? I can't `InputStream` to serve me any bytes, even though the file is certainly available and non empty. http://i.imgur.com/bCkl41l.png

Comment: You have to `open()` a stream ...

Comment: @MartinR Hahahaha I didn't see it! It's tucked away in the super class. Thanks!